# Boost field on index in Elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

I'm using Elastic 1.7.3 and I would like to have a boost on some fields in a index with documents like this fictional example :

```
{
title: "Mickey Mouse",
content: "Mickey Mouse is a fictional ...",
related_articles: [
    {"title": "Donald Duck"},
    {"title": "Goofy"}
]
}
```

Here eg: title is really important, content too, `related_articles` is a bit more important. My real document have lot of fields and nested object.

I would like to give more weight to the title field than content, and more to content than related_articles.

I have seen the `title^5` way, but I must use it at each query and I must (I guess) list all my fields instead of a "_all" query.
I do a lot of search but I found lot of deprecated solutions (`_boost` by eg).

As I used to work with Sphinx : I search something that works like the field weight option where you can give some weight to field that are really important in your index than others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that the `_boost` meta-field that you could use at the type level has been deprecated.

But you can still use the [`boost` property](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/index-boost.html) when defining each field in your mapping, which will boost your field at indexing time.

Your mapping would look like this:

```
{
    "my_type": {
        "properties": {
            "title": {
                "type": "string", "boost": 5
            },
            "content": {
                "type": "string", "boost": 4
            },
            "related_articles": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "title": {
                        "type": "string", "boost": 3
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You have to be aware, though, that it's not necessarily a good idea to boost your field at index time, because once set, you cannot change it unless you are willing to re-index all of your documents, whereas using query-time boosting achieves the same effect and can be changed more easily.

Comment: Right, I'am aware of the pro and cons about index time or query time. In my case, index time seems a better idea (because our content have strong and weak field, and if we want to query a specific field we will use a field query).

Thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: Just to be sure : when we made a boost at a query time, it's with the "^5" notation right?
So we need to list all fields we need in the query right?

Comment: Ok, fair enough if you're aware of the downsides, no problem. Yes, the query-time boosting notation is correct.